# I'm trying to lower my player's gravity at the apex of their jump and increase it on the way down (2D Game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, physics

My player's gravity decreases at the apex of their jump, but it doesn't change after that. I want the gravity to increase a set amount of time after the apex.

I have it set up to detect the apex of my jump by if I'm jumping and if my y velocity is in the negatives. I then have several bools set up to switch between increased gravity and decreased gravity which I toggle using if statements. I have the if statement that switches the decrease and increase gravity bools referencing a float I made to act as a counter. The counter resets to 0.2 when you aren't jumping, and inside the if statement that determines the apex of the jump I have "gravityCounter -= Time.deltaTime" to count it down when you reach said apex.

For whatever reason, it seems that the counter never actually goes any lower; anyone know what's wrong?

This is the script:

{

```
public bool increaseGravity = false;
public bool decreaseGravity = false;
public float gravityCounter;
public float gravity = 0.2f;
public float gravityModifierDown = 2.75f;
public float gravityModifierUp = 4.25f;
public float normalGravity = 3.5f;
bool highPoint = false;

[SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Update()
{   
    

    if (rb.velocity.y < 0 && this.highPoint == false && gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().isJumping == true)
    {
        
        this.highPoint = true;
        Debug.Log("highPoint");
        decreaseGravity = true;
        gravityCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        gravityCounter = 0.2f;
    }

    if (rb.velocity.y > 0f || this.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().IsGrounded())
    {
        this.highPoint = false;
    }

    if (gravityCounter < 0f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Gravity Counter Empty");
        decreaseGravity = false;
        increaseGravity = true;
    }

    if (decreaseGravity == true)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = gravityModifierDown;
    }

    if (increaseGravity == true)
    {
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = gravityModifierUp;
    }

    if (this.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().IsGrounded() || this.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().IsWalled())
    {
        increaseGravity = false;
        decreaseGravity = false;
        this.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = normalGravity;
        
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The gravityCounter is not going any lower because this statement is only happening once:
`gravityCounter -= Time.deltaTime;`

That block of statements is after a conditional checking if `highpoint` is equal to true, but then you immediately set `highpoint` to false. Therefore it will only happen in one Update call and every one after will get to the else block and set `gravityCounter` back to `0.2f`.

Maybe put the `gravityCounter -=` line after `if (decreaseGravity == true)` (you don't need the "== true" btw).

Also, not related to the specific problem but I think physics related stuff like gravity should be in `FixedUpdate`

Comment: Oh my, it worked. I had to make a couple of extra edits after the fact to get it working properly, but it works perfectly now. Thanks so much for the help!

Also thanks for letting me know about the "== true" thing and about FixedUpdate :D